# How to fix resizing of text view each time when the string is changed?

Tags: android

I'm making a timer application for Android and I have a problem. Each time when the string in text view is refreshing, the text view is resizing to fill all the text. That's happening each second so you can barely see the numbers because of the fast resizing of the field. That's happening because the char "1" doesn't have same with as "0" for example. How can I say: "Okay, for each symbol you have that size." or some kind of that sort to stop that resizing and each symbol to know his size? I tried to put fixed with but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have the view wrap_content, make it a fixed size. Or possibly better, use a relative layout and anchor it to some other view left and right so it won't need to shrink/grow.

Comment: Okay, I have just change the layout_width to fixed size - it works perfectly. Thank you so much @GabeSechan

Comment: Just a warning-  you may (depending on your layout) now have sizing issues on different screen sizes.  Hard to say, but that's why fixed sizes are to be avoided when possible.

Comment: Okay @GabeSechan, now I'm have an similar problem. Now I want to set text in the centre. I tried with `android:gravity="center"` but the moving is now appears. In other words, if I have a fixed `layout_width` and `gravity` set, the problem is still reproducing again. Any idea how to fix this issue?